# Header files recursion in C

Tags: c, struct, header

I have this situation:

**A.h** and **B.h**

In **A.h**:

```
typedef struct TypeA TypeA_t;
struct TypeA {
    ...
    TypeA_t *a;
    void (*doSomething)(TypeB_t *);
};
```

In **B.h**:

```
typedef struct TypeB TypeB_t;
struct TypeB {
    ...
    TypeB_t *b;
    TypeA_t something;
};
```

What is the correct way to include header files in each file?

If I include `A.h` in `B.h` and `B.h` in `A.h` I get:

`error: unknown type name 'TypeB_t'` in `A.h`

and

`error: unknown type name 'TypeA_t'` in `B.h`

I found a similar question here but it doesn't work in my case.

Comment: There is no correct way in this case because what you're trying to do is impossible. If every `TypeA` has a `TypeB` and every `TypeB` has a `TypeA` then their size would be infinite.

Comment: If you use proper include guards you will probably always run into that same issues even if you switch to pointers (which you must do anyway). You might introduce a more basic header providing some forward declarations for your types.

Comment: @tkausl I changed the structure, in one struct I have a function pointer

Comment: Please [edit] and turn this into a [mcve]

Comment: Quick solution: Pointers and forward declarations (like the ones you already have).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way you've defined your code, `TypeA` can live with a forward reference to `TypeB`, but `TypeB` needs the full declaration of `TypeA` to compile.

In other words, you need to do two things. First forward define `TypeB` in `a.h` before your class definition (because pointers can work with partial definitions):

```
//a.h
typedef struct TypeB TypeB_t;

typedef struct TypeA TypeA_t;
struct TypeA {
...
TypeA_t *a;
void (*doSomething)(TypeB_t*);
};
```

And then include `a.h` from `b.h` to get the declaration for your class (because you use the full `TypeA` class as a field type):

```
// b.h
#include "a.h"

typedef struct TypeB TypeB_t;
struct TypeB {
...
TypeB_t *b;
TypeA_t something;
};
```

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work. Same error: unknown type in `A.h`

Comment: You declare `struct TypeB_t`, and then use just `TypeB_t` later on. (both in `A.h`)

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso that's what I tried but I get the same error

Comment: @Alex I'm saying Blindy made a typo. It should be `typedef struct TypeB TypeB_t` instead of just `struct TypeB_t`.

Comment: @Alex, that's somewhere else in the code. The code here does not deference anything of type `TypeB_t`.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I only know C++ really and tried to adapt it. I'll edit it in :)

Comment: `#include "b.h"` will define the `TypeB_t` typedef twice (once in the nested `#include "a.h"`). That is OK in C11, but is invalid in C99 or C90. The duplicate `typedef` could be removed from "b.h" to prevent that.

Comment: @Blindy C doesn't automatically `typedef` anything for you, unlike C++.

Answer (score 1):

The `typedef`s can be moved to other header files, and use header guard macros to prevent multiple definitions:

**At.h**

```
#ifndef AT_H_INCLUDED_
#define AT_H_INCLUDED_

typedef struct TypeA TypeA_t;

#endif
```

**Bt.h**

```
#ifndef BT_H_INCLUDED_
#define BT_H_INCLUDED_

typedef struct TypeB TypeB_t;

#endif
```

**A.h**

```
#ifndef A_H_INCLUDED_
#define A_H_INCLUDED_

#include "At.h"
#include "Bt.h"

struct TypeA {
    TypeA_t *a;
    void (*doSomething)(TypeB_t *);
};

#endif
```

**B.h**

```
#ifndef B_H_INCLUDED_
#define B_H_INCLUDED_

#include "Bt.h"
#include "A.h"

struct TypeB {
    TypeB_t *b;
    TypeA_t something;
};

#endif
```

.c files shouldn't need to include "At.h" or "Bt.h". The inclusion of "At.h" and "Bt.h" can be policy restricted to be included only by the main header files. Including "A.h" will fully define `TypeA_t`. Including "B.h" will fully define `TypeB_t` (and will also fully define `TypeA_t`). They can be included in any order.